# How to determin size of internal flash for target?

Tags: stm32, dfu

I want to upload the device firmware to a file using dfu-util. How can I determine the correct size of flash memory?

After booting the device into DFU it can be found using:

```
dfu-util -l
```

For which I receive the following information:

```
Found DFU: [0483:df11] ver=2200, devnum=8, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=1, name="@Option Bytes  /0x1FFFF800/01*016 e", serial="FFFFFFFEFFFF"
Found DFU: [0483:df11] ver=2200, devnum=8, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=0, name="@Internal Flash  /0x08000000/064*0002Kg", serial="FFFFFFFEFFFF"
```

To upload the flash configuration to a file I need to determine the size of flash memory. Based on [this article](https://fishpepper.de/2016/09/02/flashing-betaflight-into-a-bangood-happymodel-f3-evo-brushed-flight-controller/) the size would be 64 x 1kB of flash memory.

What is the meaning of 'Kg' in 0002Kg?
 
The instructions I am following (elsewhere, for a different device, see above) is using `128 x 1kB`, instead which I believe is incorrect. 
How can I calculate the size of flash memory and what will happen if I set the memory size too large to download an image?

The command is:

```
dfu-util -a 0 -s 0x08000000:131072 -U ./original.bin
```

I think it should be

```
dfu-util -a 0 -s 0x08000000:65536 -U ./original.bin
```

Comment: When I set the memory size too large it seems that any invalid address returns 0xFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [UM0290](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/cc/6d/c3/43/ea/29/4b/eb/CD00135281.pdf/files/CD00135281.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00135281.pdf) in which we find:

> Each Alternate setting string descriptor must follow this memory mapping else the PC 
>   Host Software would be able to decode the right mapping for the selected device:
>
> - `@`: To detect that this is a special mapping descriptor (to avoid decoding standard
>     descriptor)
> - `/`: for separator between zones
> - Maximum 8 digits per address starting by “0x”
> - `/`: for separator between zones
> - Maximum of 2 digits for the number of sectors
> - `*` : For separator between number of sectors and sector size
> - Maximum 3 digits for sector size between 0 and 999
> - 1 digit for the sector size multiplier. Valid entries are: `B` (byte), `K` (Kilo), `M` (Mega)
> - 1 digit for the sector type as follows:
>
>   - `a` (0x41): Readable
>   - `b` (0x42): Erasable
>   - `c` (0x43): Readable and Erasable
>   - `d` (0x44): Writeable
>   - `e` (0x45): Readable and Writeable
>   - `f` (0x46): Erasable and Writeable
>   - `g` (0x47): Readable, Erasable and Writeable

So your string really does mean that the internal flash is 64 sectors of 2 KB, and that they are "readable, erasable and writable" (i.e. flash). Are you sure about your expectations of the device's flash layout?

Comment: The OP's example has, `name="@Internal Flash  /0x08000000/064*0002Kg"` has space for what appears to be a 3 digits for the number of sectors and 4 digits for sector size. Is there an updated version of `UM0290` to address the extra digits?